# Equivalent of RigidBody2D's body_exited on StaticBody2D?

Tags: collision-detection, godot, gdscript

I'm building a type of Pinball game using Godot 4.0. I've got two types of components relevant to this question:

- **balls**, represented as a `RigidBody2D` scene with `Sprite` and circular `CollisionShape2D` children
- **circular bumpers**, represented as a `StaticBody2D` scene with `Sprite` and circular `CollisionShape2D` children

When a ball hits *any* object, that *other* object should be "in charge" (code-wise) of what happens; at least, to get some clean code. However, the `body_exited` signal is only available on the balls' node type, but not available on `StaticBody2D`.

**I'd *want* to write (pseudo-code):**

```
# In StaticBody2D BumperCircular.gd:
func _on_body_exited(body):
    if is_ball(body):
        # add bonus velocity because of the bump
```

I feel like I'm missing something, because it seems wrong to add `body_exited` on the Ball and then dispatch/delegate back to the other body for logic on what happens next.

**So I feel like I *have* to write:**

```
# In RigidBody2D Ball.gd:
func _on_body_exited(body):
    if is_bumper(body):
        # logic for bumper coded inside this script
    else if is_some_component(body):
        # logic for component type 2 coded inside this script
    else if is_some_component(body):
        # logic for component type 3 coded inside this script
    # etc.
        # etc.
```

Or at best:

```
# In RigidBody2D Ball.gd:
func _on_body_exited(body):
    if has_ball_collision_logic(body):
        body.on_ball_collision_logic(this) # dispatch to the other object for logic
```

But both seem to me the wrong way around.

What am I missing here? **Why is there no `body_exited` on `StaticBody2D`?**

PS. I've [searched this Stack Exchange site](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/search?q=body_exited+on+StaticBody2D) and [online in general](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Godot+body_exited+StaticBody2D), plus I've peered through [the (inheritance tree of the) StaticBody2D documentation](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_staticbody2d.html) but found no relevant info yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note**: even thought this answer is written for 2D, equivalent approaches would work for 3D.

---

**Solution 1: Use a `RigidBody2D`.**

You can set the `freeze` property of your `RigidBody2D` to `true`, and its `freeze_mode` to `FREEZE_MODE_STATIC` which will make it not move just like an `StaticBody2D`.

However, apparently the signals won't be enabled unless you set it to `FREEZE_MODE_KINEMATIC`.

---

**Solution 2: Duck type it.**

This idea would almost work:

> ```
> # In RigidBody2D Ball.gd:
> func _on_body_exited(body):
>     if has_ball_collision_logic(body):
>         body.on_ball_collision_logic(this)
> ```

To make it work, you can check for the particular method you are going to call:

```
func _on_body_exited(body):
    if body.has_method(&"on_ball_collision_logic"):
        body.on_ball_collision_logic(this)
```

---

**Solution 3: Give an `Area2D` to your `StaticBody2D` (or `CharacterBody2D`)**

Your `StaticBody2D` (or `CharacterBody2D`) can't detect collisions, but an `Area2D` can. So you can add `Area2D` as a child of it, in such way that it has identical position and colliders, it can detect the collisions for the `StaticBody2D` (or `CharacterBody2D`).

---

**Solution 4: Make the `StaticBody2D` (or `CharacterBody2D`) detect collisions.**

We are going to add an `_integrate_forces` callback to the `StaticBody2D` (or `CharacterBody2D`) using `body_set_force_integration_callback`:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    PhysicsServer2D.body_set_force_integration_callback(
        get_rid(),
        _integrate_forces
    )

func _integrate_forces(PhysicsDirectBodyState2D state, userdata) -> void:
    pass
```

Next we will ask `PhysicsDirectBodyState2D` for contacts, but for that to work we need to set how many contacts we want to get:

```
func _ready() -> void:
    var body_rid := get_rid()
    PhysicsServer2D.body_set_force_integration_callback(
        body_rid,
        _integrate_forces
    )
    body_set_max_contacts_reported(body_rid, 32)

func _integrate_forces(PhysicsDirectBodyState2D state, userdata) -> void:
    for index in state.get_contact_count():
        var body := state.get_contact_collider_object(index) as PhysicsBody2D
```

And then we will keep track of them, so we can emit signals:

```
signal body_entered(body:Node)
signal body_exited(body:Node)

var colliding_bodies := {}

func _ready() -> void:
    var body_rid := get_rid()
    PhysicsServer2D.body_set_force_integration_callback(
        body_rid,
        _integrate_forces
    )
    body_set_max_contacts_reported(body_rid, 32)

func _integrate_forces(PhysicsDirectBodyState2D state, userdata) -> void:
    var new_colliding_bodies := {}
    for index in state.get_contact_count():
        var body := state.get_contact_collider_object(index) as PhysicsBody2D
        if not is_instance_valid(body):
            continue

        new_colliding_bodies[body] = body
        if not colliding_bodies.has(body):
            body_entered.emit(body)

    for body in colliding_bodies.keys():
        if not new_colliding_bodies.has(body):
            body_exited.emit(body)

    colliding_bodies = new_colliding_bodies
```

And there you have `body_entered` and `body_exited` added to your `StaticBody2D` (or `CharacterBody2D`).

---

> Why is there no `body_exited` on `StaticBody2D`?

The engine does not need to put the work for the `StaticBody2D` body to detect collisions because the `StaticBody2D` won't react to collisions. So these are not offered out of the box.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the comprehensive answer. Gives me something to work with , plus taught me a more generic thing or two!

Comment: PS. I went with option 2 for the moment, but I did need to use `self` instead of `this` everywhere, or I'd get "Identifier 'this' not declared in the current scope." - perhaps a 4.0 thing?

Comment: @Jeroen no, it is `self` in GDScript for Godot 3.x or 4 (it would be `this` in C#, but this is not C#). I just assumed you had some variable called `this`.

Comment: For solution 1 to work, I actually had to set `freeze_mode` to `FREEZE_MODE_KINEMATIC` to receive `_on_body_entered` and `_on_body_exited` signals. No signals received when `freeze_mode` is `FREEZE_MODE_STATIC`.