# StaticBody2D on body enter without Area2D

Tags: physics, godot

How can I get the `body_entered` signal on a `StaticBody2D` without an `Area2D`? I know workarounds exits but what I want is a custom solution using `PhysicsServer2D` that makes it fire the `body_entered` signal and keep track of old bodies so it fires `body_exited` signal as well.

I've tried the #4 method mentioned in [this question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/204774/33287)
that uses `PhysicsServer2D` but it seems not to work anymore.
Since I want a native solution to add these signals on a `StaticBody2D` rather than relying on adding `Area2D` which requires maintaining 2 collision shapes.

Here's a section from [the docs](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_physicsserver2d.html#class-physicsserver2d-method-body-set-force-integration-callback) that caught my attention:

> "Note: This callback is currently not called in Godot Physics."

Comment: What other question are you referring to?

Comment: this one ->  [Equivalent of RigidBody2D's body_exited on StaticBody2D?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/204774/equivalent-of-rigidbody2ds-body-exited-on-staticbody2d)

Comment: I've edited to include that info directly into the question. The other question lists 4 alternative solutions - it's not clear which you've tried, what you expected to get & how it differed from the outcome. It might also to describe your overall goal. I would try adding an Area2D as a child & signal up as needed (solution #3 in linked post). Can you edit to elaborate on why that option doesn't fit your situation ?

Comment: thanks, that's so nice of you.
I meant the #4 one which uses the PhysicsServer2D

Comment: I see, yes, that solution does not appear to work. Is there any reason you want to avoid an area for this? In particular, it could be possible to add an area using the physics server instead of a node, would that suffice?

Comment: @Theraot just experimenting with the engine to see its capabilities, and another thing that Im trying to replicate what I had with unity `on_collision_enter`, but my whole point is that Im exploring how the godot physics engine works or how to tweak to my liking